# How to get text from txt file

Tags: php, javascript, html

I'm creating a html template with notification under nav bar , and admin can change that notification from the system the text of notification bar will be from notetxt file from the same location path where index.html is located i ave tried

```
<?php
foreach (glob("note.txt") as $filename) { 
  readfile($filename);
}
?>
```

and many other way but nothing happens it still stay blank

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> *i'm using this code in pure html file*

### You can't use `PHP` functions in plain `HTML` file. **MUST** be written in a PHP file.

You have now in your code:

```
<span>
<!--?php

 foreach (glob("note.txt") as $filename) { 
 $fileArr = file_get_contents($filename);
 }
?-->
</span>
```

Try with the examples above in a proper PHP file... then must work.

Comment: Good catch. did not mention that. @Arsh what he means is change your .html file to .php, because html works in php, but php doesn't in html :)

Comment: @ArshSingh Accept this answer. because this was the only one that worked. or did you used some of the code we posted too?

Comment: @Arsh, @Kees mean that your problem was not only in the `PHP` code that you provide as example, initially was the way you was applying it. But as you also have some PHP missing code, you can mark as accepted answer the one you think that helps you as much, **and could help others too**. (and if is necessary, after that we can edit our answers to fit the final solution)

Answer (score 1):

You are not echoing out the content of the textfile.

do it like this:

```
$myFile = "note.txt";
$fh = fopen($myFile, 'r');
$theData = fread($fh, filesize($myFile));
fclose($fh);
echo $theData;
```

This will output your content of the file.

Comment: it still remain blank nothing displays ,,, in note.txt file have only this line : try line , and when i try to add the php code it remain blank nothing displays

Comment: this is the link to my template : http://www.punjabonnet.com/Heartline/    blue bar is used for notification

Answer (score 0):

you can use file_get_contents function,
try something like this :

```
<?php

 foreach (glob("note.txt") as $filename) { 
 $fileArr = file_get_contents($filename);
 }
?>
```

Comment: it still blank nothing happens ,,, i'm using this code in pure html file , is there any other way to display the text from txt file into html file ?

Comment: this is the link to my template , the blue bar is used for notification : http://www.punjabonnet.com/Heartline/

Answer (score 0):

It's very simple use [file_get_contents();](https://www.php.net/file_get_contents)

```
<?= file_exists('note.txt') ? file_get_contents("note.txt") : "file doesn't exists"; ?>
```

That is all what you need. [file_get_contents()](https://www.php.net/file_get_contents) get the content of file and returns it. I've also checked if file exists because it may be your problem. Also make sure you have proper rights to read the file(CHMOD) and file is not empty.

Comment: Note. do not use shorttags in examples. it could be that the server from OP is not supporting it.

Comment: I couldn't also use PHP5 because server doesn't support it. It's in PHP and also since PHP 5.4.0 it's always available.

Comment: is there any way to show the content of file in html file by not using php ?

Comment: There's no way, you need to use server side language. It doesn't have to be PHP it can be for example asp.net but it needs to be server side language. Browser doesn't have access to server files.

Comment: No you can't open a txt file using html. It's just as simple is changing the extension from .html to .php if you're working on a server/localhost with php and apache.

Comment: You can also add php parser to html files in .htaccess add this line `AddType application/x-httpd-php .php .html`

Comment: i've changed fomrat of file to .php as @KeesSonnema said and now it works fine

Comment: If you'd added this line to your .htaccess or apache configuration it would work fine too :) It's about server configuration and what files are parsed by PHP.

Comment: Actually @ArshSingh. It wasn't me that told you so. it was gmo that did. I just translated it to 'easy to read' text.

Comment: so by adding that line into .htaccess file the code php will work fine in html file?

Comment: @Robert i have tried to add it in .htaccess file but when i've reloaded the page it takes me to the error 404 page